# SHFileOperation - File only copy

Tags: c++

Here is some code that transfers the contents of the A drive into C:\test\disk1. The program compiles and runs fine. The program creates a folder called "Floppy disk drive (A)" and the contents are contained within. Is it possible to just copy the files from the A drive without the folder?

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    const wchar_t *const sourceFile = L"A:\\\0";
    const wchar_t *const outputFile = L"C:\\test\\disk1\0";

    SHFILEOPSTRUCTW fileOperation;
    memset(&fileOperation, 0, sizeof(SHFILEOPSTRUCTW));

    fileOperation.wFunc = FO_COPY;
    fileOperation.fFlags = FOF_SILENT | FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR | FOF_NOERRORUI | FOF_FILESONLY;
    fileOperation.pFrom = sourceFile;
    fileOperation.pTo = outputFile;

    int result = SHFileOperationW(&fileOperation);
    if (result != 0)
    {
        printf("SHFileOperation Failure: Error%u\n", result);
        return 1;
    }

    memset(&fileOperation, 0, sizeof(SHFILEOPSTRUCTW));

    printf("Transfer complete\n");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the reference of the `SHFILEOPSTRUCTW` structure:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759795(v=vs.85).aspx

> FOF_FILESONLY 
>      Perform the operation only on files (not on folders) if a wildcard file name (*.*) is specified.

The full solution will be something like this:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    const wchar_t *const sourceFile = L"A:\\*.*\0";
    const wchar_t *const outputFile = L"C:\\test\\disk1\0";

    SHFILEOPSTRUCTW fileOperation;
    memset(&fileOperation, 0, sizeof(SHFILEOPSTRUCTW));

    fileOperation.wFunc = FO_COPY;
    fileOperation.fFlags = FOF_SILENT | FOF_NOCONFIRMATION | FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR | FOF_NOERRORUI | FOF_FILESONLY;
    fileOperation.pFrom = sourceFile;
    fileOperation.pTo = outputFile;

    int result = SHFileOperationW(&fileOperation);
    if (result != 0)
    {
        printf("SHFileOperation Failure: Error%u\n", result);
        return 1;
    }

    memset(&fileOperation, 0, sizeof(SHFILEOPSTRUCTW));

    printf("Transfer complete\n");

}
```

Comment: Cheers Betontalpfa. I get this error when I compile. 'C:\C++\shfileop\main.cpp|16|error: expected unqualified-id before numeric constant|' Any suggestions?

Comment: FOF_FILESONLY
   Perform the operation only on files (not on folders) if a wildcard file name (\*.*) is specified.

Comment: Yes I want all files to transfer from the A drive. But it wont compile. Could you elaborate more please?